# How to install Windows 10 in Qemu on macOS Monterey?

Tags: macos, qemu

I am using macOS Monterey I am trying to install Windows 10 on my system using Qemu. I am using below codes in my Mac terminal

```
qemu-img create -f raw -o size=20G Windows10.img

qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -cdrom '/Volumes/Win10_21H1_English_x64.iso' -m 14048M -hda Windows10.img
```

However after sometime, my installation is failing with below message :

[image]

Could you please help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Don't go nuts trying to deal with Qemu’s complex command line stuff. Just [download and use UTM](https://mac.getutm.app) which is effectively Emu with a nice GUI on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-m 8G \
-monitor stdio \
-usb \
-device usb-tablet \
-device intel-hda \
-boot d \
-drive file=windows10.qcow2 \
-drive file=Win10_21H2_EnglishInternational_x64.iso,media=cdrom \
-machine type=q35,accel=hvf \
-cpu Haswell
```

Please use specific cpu (your host cpu) instead of "-cpu host"

https://github.com/utmapp/UTM/issues/2368